# UITableView scroll is never end after search

Tags: objective-c, uitableview

I have UITableView to show whole bunch of words from array.

I also provide search bar on top of table view so when people type a word in textbox search then my code start filtering data from array.

My result is good but my scroll in tableview is never end even though there is only one row.
My tableview result can scroll down and down without no row.

I don't know what going on with my table view.

My code that I have implement.

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    if(self.tableView == tableView){
        return [self.alphabet count];
    }else{
        return 1;
    }
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    if (self.tableView == tableView) {
        return [[self.vocabularyInfo objectAtIndex:section] count];
    }else{
        return [self.filteredVocabs count];
    }
}
-(NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [self.alphabet objectAtIndex:section];
}

 - (NSArray *)sectionIndexTitlesForTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    if(self.tableView == tableView){
         return self.alphabet;
    }else{
        return nil;
    }
}
```

// Display cell

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSString *cellIdentifier = @"CommentTableCell";
    //-- try to get a reusable cell --
    CommentTableCell *cell = (CommentTableCell *) [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
    //-- create new cell if no reusable cell is available --
    if (cell == nil)
    {
        NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:cellIdentifier owner:self options:nil];
        cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];
    }

    VocabularyController *vc;

    // Display word from database else display vocabulary when searching
    if (tableView != self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView) {
        vc = [self.vocabularyInfo[indexPath.section] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    }else{
        vc = [self.filteredVocabs objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    }

    cell.nameLabel.text = vc.korean;

    return cell;
}
```

// My method that I used for filtering my array to display the result

```
- (BOOL)searchDisplayController:(UISearchDisplayController *)controller shouldReloadTableForSearchString:(NSString *)searchString{
    if (searchString.length > 0) {
        NSArray *vocabToSearch = self.vocabularyInfo;
        if (self.currentSearchString.length > 0 && [searchString rangeOfString:self.currentSearchString].location == 0) {
            vocabToSearch = self.filteredVocabs;
        }
        NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"korean CONTAINS[cd] %@", searchString];
        self.filteredVocabs = [vocabToSearch filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
    } else {
        self.filteredVocabs = self.vocabularyInfo;
    }
    self.currentSearchString = searchString;

    return YES;
}
```

Please help me!!

Answer (score 0):

Check your tableview's datasource delegate function. 
Maybe more detail about your implementation is helpful.

Comment: I have checked already.
I spent almost 2 days ago. Nothing can help.
Is it because of uitableview that running on iOS 7 ?

Answer (score 0):

Please check the value you are returning for the number of rows in the following method:

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
```

Comment: I have checked already.
My result was only one row. Still my tableview can scroll down and down about more 10 rows and then no cell anymore but white screen only.
So how to solve it!!